# Removing &PageSpeed=noscript from the end of URL IIS Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the last part of the URL with IIS Rewrite, but somewhere I do the things wrong.
Example URL:
https://example.com/BGLog/pages/register/?ReturnUrl=/blog/arebemagare/site/posts/?bid=37780&PageSpeed=noscript
I need to remove &PageSpeed=noscript
I wroted rule, but it strips also ?ReturnUrl=/blog/arebemagare/site/posts/?bid=3778 :

```
 <rule name="Remove paging parameters" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)?$" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(.*)&amp;PageSpeed=noscript(.*)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Please learn more about regular expressions so that you can write the proper patterns. 2) Enable FRT to learn how the rules are used internally https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

I think I've achieved it, but with two rules:

```
   <rule name="Remove &PageSpeed" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(&amp;PageSpeed=noscript)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}?{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
<rule name="Remove ?PageSpeed" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)?$" />
  <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(PageSpeed=.+)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following rule：

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)&amp;(PageSpeed=noscript)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}?{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

The result of my test is working, hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

It works! But I found it catches also https://example.com/BGLog/blog/filteredlist?cat=5021&PageSpeed=noscript and rewrites it to
https://example.com/BGLog/blog/filteredlist

I've tried to edit it to not strip ?cat=5021, but without success :(